# How to validate bundle hash

Tags: iri-legacy-api, bundles, validation

I've been working with a C# port of the API and have managed to get messages posted to the tangle.
As most of these are zero values I thought I'd try reattach.online to help get them confirmed.
When I do this it complains about an invalid bundle hash.

Does anyone know of a tool which helps you validate if your bundle hash is valid?
I've been using the java reference but I'm wondering if it's up to date.

Comment: I'm using **iota.lib.js** and also receive the error > Error: Invalid bundle provided In my code I get some transaction objects with `Iota.api.getTransactionsObjects()`. The returned objects I feed into `Iota.api.getBundle()` which then sometimes returns the error message.
How can I identify invalid bundles upfront and why is this message created anyway? Can someone explain?

Comment: @EricXyz that does not answer the question

Answer (score 1):

The Java port is up to date - it is used in the Android wallet. Also, obviously the JavaScript port is up to date - it is used in the official desktop wallet.

The C# port is not up to date as it (still) uses the old CURL hashing function (used until beginning of August 2017).

Comment: Cheers, yeah the C# project is really old. I'm working on a better port of it and have implemented the KERL hashing for bundles, address creation and POW. 
All of this appears to be working but nothing is being accepted on the tangle. 

What I'm looking for is a way to validate the transaction is valid before posting it.